# Javascript "tuple" notation: what is its point?

Tags: javascript, syntax, tuples, comma-operator

At [wtfjs](https://wtfjs.com/wtfs/2011-02-11-all-your-commas-are-belong-to-Array), I found that the following is legal javascript.

```
",,," == Array((null,'cool',false,NaN,4)); // true
```

The argument `(null,'cool',false,NaN,4)` looks like a tuple to me, but javascript does not have tuples!

Some quick tests in my javascript console yields the following.

```
var t = (null,'cool',false,NaN,4); // t = 4
(null,'cool',false,NaN,4) === 4; // true
(alert('hello'), 42); // shows the alert and returns 42
```

It appears to behave exactly like a semicolon `;` separated list of statements, simply returning the value of the last statement.

Is there a reference somewhere that describes this syntax and its semantics? Why does it exist, i.e. when should it be used?

Comment: It is the comma operator: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

Comment: The comma operator can also be (ab)used to run a series of functions inside of a ternary branch, as it will return the result of the last statement anyway: `var a = isTrue ? (b=f(c), g(b)) : (b=g(c), f(b))`. Rarely wise, but sometimes useful if very concise code is preferred over readability, or for quick debugging purposes.

Comment: This is called an 'expression' in JavaScript, this is not simply an effect of the comma operator though it plays a small part; This expression is resolved because of the comma operator. You can set a value to any mutable variable of any evaluated expression. Even if that expression is undefined.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are seeing the effect of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

The resultant value when `a,b,c,...,n` is evaluated will always be the value of the rightmost expression, however *all* expressions in the chain are still evaluated (from left to right).

Comment: Thanks, the term 'comma operator' is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

As already explained this behaviour is caused by `,` operator. Due to this the expression `(null,'cool',false,NaN,4)` will always evaluate to `4`. So we have

```
",,," == Array(4)
```

`Array(4)` - creates new array with allocated 4 elements. At the time of comparison with the string this array is converted to string like it would be with `Array(4).toString()`. For arrays `toString` acts like `join(',')` method called on this array. So for the empty array of 4 elements join will produce the string `",,,"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `alert((null,'cool',false,NaN,4))` and then you can see.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LTNVv/)

The reason is because the comma operator evaluates all the statements and return the last one.

Think of this line: `a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;` it will run each expression so in essence it will set the variables to what you want and return the last value (in this case 3)