# Adding several values in one CSV line Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

is there a way to do this? Im not to good with javascript brackets etc...

```
item: ($('input#title'+id).val(),$('input#qty'+id).val(),$('input#price'+id).val()),
```

I tried the above but it only gives me the last values,

Firebug gives me:

```
item_1  7
item_2  7
item_3  7
item_4  7
item_5  7
```

What im after is:

```
item_1  Burgers,3,12.50
item_2  Sandwiches,7,7.50
item_3  Fries,10,5.50
item_4  Drinks,10,2.50
item_5  Pancakes,12,7.50
```

I want to do it this way because it just would be easier to grab that csv array and then insert the data per row.

Im basically inserting the data into a mysql table where i can display it for the client as a food order.

Thanks in advance
Jonny

Comment: Thank you, is it worth a post from you? so i can give the green tick? or should i just add an edit to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use square brackets instead, assuming you want an array.

```
item: [$('input#title'+id).val(),$('input#qty'+id).val(),$('input#price'+id).val()],
```

Here is a post that explains your initial problem: 
[Javascript "tuple" notation: what is its point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018295/javascript-tuple-notation-what-is-its-point)